# Minecraft Sound Output

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing a custom modpack, and it takes a good 6-7 minutes to load - even on a beefy pc - so I don't really like having to relog, but when I turn off my headphones to charge them, after turning them back on, Minecraft no longer plays sound through them.

It seems that disconnecting the audio output stops Minecraft sounds until you reload the game.

I've tested this with some Steam games, and as well as YouTube, and it would seem that the problem is ***Minecraft related***. The issue does not present itself in any other environments

Is there any way I could bypass this? I had an idea of basically instead of connecting My headphones to MC, I could pair them as:

Headphones --> Program --> Minecraft

So that the program would always get the audio, then play it to my headphones, but I have no idea ***if*** a program like this exists, and if it does, what on earth it's called.

Comment: 1. If you start a YouTube video (specifically YouTube, best in Chrome), disconnect and reconnect the headphones while keeping it running, can you then hear it without doing anything special? 2. Try F3+T and F3+R (I don't know which one it is) after reconnecting the headphones. Does that fix it? The game might freeze for a few seconds, because it reloads all resources. 3. If #1 works and #2 doesn't work, you can turn on showing the game log in the launcher and in that, set it to "debug" (or whatever sounds like the most detailed), exit and start the game again (so that the setting is applied...

Comment: ...immediately) and then copy it all into a pastebin and link it here? Maybe latest.log also shows the same, but I'm not sure, it could be less detailed. Please also say at which time (by second if possible) you disconnected and reconnected the headphones.

Comment: Technically this should be tagged "technical-problems", but since that tag is full of "my game crashes pls help", I won't add it. I personally block questions tagged with that, but this one here is much more interesting.

Comment: Unless Minecraft is the only program to do this, this isn't a gaming specific problem; its how Windows detects and uses your headphones.

Comment: @Fabian I tested what you asked about YouTube, and yes, I can still hear, So that's not it. I'll test the F3+T and F3+R, then move on to logs

Comment: @Frank As I stated Chrome seems to be fine with it, and I've also tested with other games such as Prey, and a few other steam games, all which work fine (output sound after reconnecting)

Comment: F3+T will reload resource packs which can fix sound but could cause the long stall just like startup.

Comment: That's critical information that should be part of your question; without it, it honestly sounds like a problem with your computer.

Comment: @Frank Done and dusted

Answer (score 1):

Very simple fix. As first suggested by Fabian, and later restated by IronAnvil, the F3 + T key combo fixed the issue! It did, however, also produce a 30 second - 1 1/2 minute lag spike, as all the resources were reloaded.

Comment: If you want to, you can still do the log thing, but to be able to make a bug report, you would first have to find out if Vanilla Minecraft causes it and if not, which mod. That takes a long time, but it can mean that the issue gets completely fixed.

Comment: @Fabian it's not just a modded thing, this happens in vanilla as well, so I'll make a report later